# Existence of a basis for which a given diagonalizable matrix $M$ and $\lambda I_n$ are both diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A = \lambda I_n$ and $M$ is an $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrix.  Show that there exists a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ with respect to which both $A$ and $M$ are diagonalizable.

**My proof:**

Suppose $M$ is diagonalizable, then there exists a basis of eigenvectors $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ wrt which $M$ is a diagonal matrix.  We want to show that $A$ is also diagonal with respect to this basis.

Clearly, $Bv_i = \alpha_i v_i$ and also since $A = \lambda I$, we have $A v_i = \lambda v_i$

But we have that:

$(AB)v_i = A(Bv_i) = A(\alpha_i v_i) = \alpha_i(A v_i) = \alpha_i(\lambda v_i) = \lambda(\alpha_i v_i) = \lambda(B v_i) = B(\lambda v_i) = B(A v_i) = (BA)v_i$

Which tells me that they share the same eigenvectors.  Am I done?  I'm not sure where the punchline is.  I know I am on the right path but I need some help.

Comment: In every basis $A = \lambda I$

Comment: So it's trivial, all I have to say is that $B$ gives us this basis of eigenvectors and $A$ is diagonal wrt to this basis by virtue of being a constant multiple of the identify matrix, correct?  Nothing else to show?

Comment: Any two commuting operators on a Hilbert space are simultaneously diagonalizable if they commute, and every operator commutes with identity.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have the notion of a Hilbert space here.